# Including a plist file with my cocoapod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, plist

I am building a private framework to be used within a private pod specs repository. Lets call the framework "IOSExampleFramework".

I am having a problem trying to bundle a plist along with my source files. An example of my pod spec is:

```
   Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "IOSExampleFramework"
  s.version      = "0.0.2"
  s.summary      = "IOSExampleFramework Framwork"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
This framework is an example framework for stack overflow question purposes.
                   DESC

  s.homepage     = "http://example.com"

  s.license      = { :type => "Custom", :text => <<-LICENSE
                   Copyright Stephen Biggerstaff
                 LICENSE
               }

  s.author             = { "Stephen Biggerstaff" => "stephen.biggerstaff@example.com" }

  s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://exampleRepo.git", :tag => "0.0.2" }
  s.source_files  = "Classes", "IOSExampleFramework/IOSExampleFramework/*.{h,m}"
  #s.resource = "DeviceIdentifiers.plist"

  s.ios.vendored_frameworks  = "IOSExampleFramework/CrashReporter.framework"

  #s.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2", 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => "-ObjC" }

end
```

My sources work fine, however the plist is in the same directory as these sources and does not pull down when I'm trying to do a pod update in the application I need it for.

I've also tried specifying a wildcard "*.plist" in resources, however I don't want to pull down info.plist, although it didn't work anyway.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else viewing this issue, I resolved it by creating a Folder called "assets" to place the Plist. I then proceeded to add the line:

```
s.resources = "CTYCrashReporter/Assets/*"
```

The pods then seemed to pull in the file fine. Unusual that it didn't work with the specific name.

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping this into your podspec:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'IOSExampleFramework' => [ 'Pod/Assets/**/*' ]
}
```

Where your `.plist` file can be found in the "`Assets`" folder you'll keep on the same folder level as "`Classes`".  You can also put other resources in the Assets folder as well.

Comment: Perhaps my placeholder name is misleading. I don't package this pod as a framework, so this didn't work. At least I'm guessing that was the issue. I've resolved it though and added my own resolution. Thanks!